# Ftdilib installed but ftdi_enable_bitbang "was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, compilation, codeblocks

I installed the ftdilib and I am trying to compile this code:

```
/* hello-ftdi.c: flash LED connected between CTS and GND.
  This example uses the libftdi API.
 Minimal error checking; written for brevity, not durability. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ftdi.h>

#define LED 0x08  /* CTS (brown wire on FTDI cable) */

int main()
 {
 unsigned char c = 0;
struct ftdi_context ftdic;

/* Initialize context for subsequent function calls */
ftdi_init(&ftdic);

/* Open FTDI device based on FT232R vendor & product IDs */
if(ftdi_usb_open(&ftdic, 0x0403, 0x6001) < 0) {
    puts("Can't open device");
    return 1;
}

/* Enable bitbang mode with a single output line */
ftdi_enable_bitbang(&ftdic, LED);

/* Endless loop: invert LED state, write output, pause 1 second */
for(;;) {
    c ^= LED;
    ftdi_write_data(&ftdic, &c, 1);
    sleep(1);
}
}
```

but there is error: ftdi_enable_bitbang was not declared in this scope
This is the only error.

Why does this keep to pop out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick look into the current version of ftdi.h shows there is no declaration for ftdi_enable_bitbang. ftdi_enable_bitbang has been removed after being deprecated for two years. Use ftdi_set_bitmode instead.